# Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64. Getting this error on checking gradle --version on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: react-native

Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64. Getting this error on checking gradle --version on Ubuntu 20.04.

Note :- Gradle 7.5.1 version installed and Environment variables are also set.

Need that on running command gradle --version should get the gradle 7.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8107

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/gradle_cache
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/gradle_dist
```